# How to stop people accessing the normal path but allowing it to be used in Mod-Rewrite

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

I am using mod-rewrite to make my urls that are really

```
www.example.com/public/questions.php?question_id= <int>
```

go to

```
www.example.com/questions/ <int>
```

How is it possible to then ban the former address from being used as a REQUEST_URI and to only  allow them through my new shortened url?

If I put a Rule

```
RewriteRule ^public public/page404_ready.php
```

that makes all my current changed urls useless too.

(And if I do accomplish all this, will I have to change all my own (AJAX) links in the page to the new URL?)

This is my file at the moment

```
RewriteRule ^questions/topics/(.+)/?$ public/questions.php?topics=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^questions/ask/?$ public/ask_question.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^questions/edit/([0-9]+)/?$ public/edit_question.php?question_id=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^questions/posts/edit/([0-9]+)/?$ public/edit_post.php?post_id=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^users/edit/([0-9]+)/?$ public/edit_profile.php?user_id=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(admin)/?$ public/$1/index.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(admin)/(\w+)/?$ public/$1/$2.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(admin)/(\w+)/(\d+)/?$ public/$1/$2.php?topic_id=$3 [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^([\w\-]+)/?$ public/$1.php [NC,L]

#RewriteRule ^public public/page404_ready.php [L]
```

Comment: (Yes, you need to change all links and ajax urls too)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't understand what exactly are you trying to do with this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^public public/page404_ready.php
```

You can use following code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# this is your current rule
RewriteRule ^questions/([0-9]+)/?$ public/questions.php?question_id=$1 [L,NC,QSA]

# this is the URL you want to block
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+public/questions\.php\?question_id=[0-9]+[&\s] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

Comment: i dont understand, i updated my question with my file at the moment, how do I stop people from going to www.example.com/public/questions.php?question_id= <int>?

Comment: 2nd rule above does exactly that i.e. blocks people going to `www.example.com/public/questions.php?question_id= <int>` If you put this rule in your .htaccess and visit that URI you will get Forbidden error.

Comment: would it be better to do this in my PHP code i.e.. to keep redirecting back to my own styled url on all those pages which only wont redirect if they enter the correct url?

Comment: `[A-Z]{3,}` basically matches HTTP methods like GET, POST, PUT, DELETE etc. Rather than code it is considered better to handle this via .htaccess itself, that is easy to maintain during future change cycles.

Comment: Wow, that really helped, thanks loads. Perhaps you can you also help me understand why my example.com/public page has a redirecting loop?

Comment: Oh that is very easy to fix. Use this code instead: `RewriteRule ^public/?$ public/page404_ready.php [L]` Problem is that you're matching only `^public` and forwarding it to `public/page404_ready.php` which again matches `^public` and this continues until Apache runs out of redirect limits and throws 500.

Comment: But it happens even if I am not referring anything to page404_ready.php ie even if I comment that part out. It is happening earlier in the code and i dont know where, thanks for your help

Comment: You also had `[L]` flag missing which indicates end of rule. With my suggested modification it should not happen.